# Avoid get multiple location when device is still stable in gps android

Tags: android

**i using simple Listner Class for get location in onchage location** 
but the device is stable then gps is getting wrong lat long  and get multliple location up to in 1000 meter.

**MyLocationListener.java**

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{        

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

//          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "change time", 5).show();

             if(location.getAccuracy() < 100.0 && location.getSpeed() >0.95){



                    Log.v("ddddddd", "fffffffff"+location.getLongitude()+location.getProvider()); 

//                       if (location.hasAccuracy() && location.getAccuracy() <= minAccuracyMeters){

                    accuracy=location.getAccuracy();
                    longitude=location.getLongitude();                            
                    latitude=location.getLatitude(); 
                    speed=(int) ((location.getSpeed()*3600)/1000);
}
}
```

Please Help me i new in android i will workin on GPS last two month.

Comment: Do not register NETWORK_PROVIDER, user GPS_PROVIDER only

Comment: i m getting location only from GPS but it gets multiple location on same place.

Comment: yes this could be a case this is why Location comes with accuracy as well.

Comment: one more problem on getting lat long from GPS. i use service for update lacation with time 35000 and distance 10 m But after some hourse gps serching is stoped automatically and can not get location after that. please give solution.

Comment: This will happen if activity you location listener registered in dies or you have unregistered location listener.

Comment: i m using service for getting location and service is register in manifest. only i start service from activity.

Comment: hi this code is working and also stop gps is resolved thr' set alarm for check status of service

Answer (score 0):

Filter the locations this way,

```
public static final int MINIMUM_ACCURACY = 50;

public static boolean isValidAndAccurateLocation(Location location) {

    boolean validLocation = location != null
            && Math.abs(location.getLatitude()) <= 90
            && Math.abs(location.getLongitude()) <= 180;
    if (validLocation && location.hasAccuracy()
            && location.getAccuracy() <= MINIMUM_ACCURACY) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide minimum distance when requesting location updates, No need to calculate distance manually. use

```
mLocationManger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, time, distance,
this);
```

Where time is `time` in milliseconds and `distance` is minimum distance in meters. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)) for full explanation.